# Why Angular project with SASS is not working?

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have been using Angular with CSS for quite a while, now I wanted to try saas so I created a new project with saas. Project created successfully, now when I'm writing code in saas file, it's throwing some errors.

1. As soon as I started writing code in saas file, I got the following error,

   Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
   SassError: Expected newline.
   ╷
   1 │ .boxModel {
   │           ^
   ╵
   src\app\header\header.component.sass 1:11  root stylesheet

When I googled this error, I got to find out that we need to install node-saas

2. So I have executed the following command

   npm install --save-dev node-sass

After it's installed it is throwing some error and installation is rollbacked, following is the error,

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'D:\\TestDocuments\\Angular11\\buildOut\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@13.8.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
gyp verb find Python - executable path is "C:\Python27\python.exe"
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python27\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - version is "2.7.7"
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.7 found at "C:\Python27\python.exe"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 13.8.0
gyp verb command install [ '13.8.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "13.8.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 13.8.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 13.8.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: D:\TestDocuments\Angular11\buildOut\node_modules\node-sass\build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? undefined
gyp verb find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp verb find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp verb find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
gyp verb find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp verb find VS - not found
gyp verb find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (D:\TestDocuments\Angular11\buildOut\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at D:\TestDocuments\Angular11\buildOut\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (D:\TestDocuments\Angular11\buildOut\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at D:\TestDocuments\Angular11\buildOut\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at D:\TestDocuments\Angular11\buildOut\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at D:\TestDocuments\Angular11\buildOut\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at D:\TestDocuments\Angular11\buildOut\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\TestDocuments\\Angular11\\buildOut\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd D:\TestDocuments\Angular11\buildOut\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v13.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@5.0.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@5.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I am not sure how to proceed after this. Can anyone guide me through this. Following are my angular.json and package.json files

package.json

```
{
  "name": "build-out",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "buildOut": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "sass"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/buildOut",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "buildOut:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "buildOut:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "buildOut:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "buildOut:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "buildOut:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "buildOut"
}
```

Comment: Is your question about sass or saas?

Comment: What is the extension of your file?

Comment: @PraneetDixit it's about sass